# Import bulk products with custom atributes fail

Tags: magento-1.9, import, magmi, import-products, avs-fastsimpleimport

I am trying to upload 100 products at once with custom attributes from backend.

First I have downloaded some products I created with custom attributes to know how can I create csv.

Now I have the correct csv and when I check data, all is correct.

[image]

The problem is when I import from there, only import 33 products without custom attributes however I have tested with 3 or 4 products and it does function very well.

I have tried with magmi using Custom Options,the magmi problem is my products dont have the same custom atributes, the header ( colum name)  changes according it.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Custom_Options

I have done all csv according magento export file and if i want to use magmi I must to change each row or Does exist another way to do that using magmi without to change my csv files ?

I hope your help. Thank you in advance

PD: My magento version is 1.9.3.6

Update 01/20/2018

I've import one product with magmi like this following this

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/Custom_Options

This example is with soccer products, for example Barcelona products have differents custom options.In this case I upload a jersey soccer with custom options like Name, Number and Patchs and it doesnt function

So if I want to upload another product in the same csv like Training jacket, it has another different custom options like: checkBox -> Pants, and it doesnt options like name,number and patchs. This is my problem because I have 2000 products in csv with different custom options per product and I think MAGMI is useful to products that have same custom options because header is same for all.

What do you think about it?

[image]

Comment: you need to follow magmi format , also all you need is enter the custom attibute code in first row and enter values in all other rows.....

Comment: There is quite some difference between custom attributes and custom options - in your question you're referring to both of them at the same time and in the same way. 
Please add some lines of your CSV you want to use with MAGMI in your question to clarify what you try to do.

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner , thank you for your reply . I've uploaded my question . Check please and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> You can put all your custom option definitions in one file and only fill up the relevant lines.

When you want to go for a custom options import using MAGMI you can follow either of these approaches:

1.
Create a CSV file for each "product type" (product type in terms of same custom options) - i.e. create one CSV for jerseys, one for pants, one for socks and so on and import them one after the other.
Pro: this might be a more tidy/readable file in case you have to modify/extend your catalog products in future for this particular set of products
Con: in return, global updates to all products however would need to be done separately in each of the CSV files (unless you can go for mass update directly in the backend)
[image]

---

2.
Create one CSV file for all products where you just keep all your custom options header on top and only fill them where needed.
[image]

Comment: Thank soo much ! . Good information